# How do I import Playlists to Amazon Music?

Tags: import, amazon-music

I have music that I have purchased from various sources and have them stored on my PC. I want to put everything on Amazon Music so that I can play them from my Amazon Echo or Amazon Dot via Alexa.

I can upload music just fine, but I cannot seem to find a way to import my playlists. I have thousands of songs and re-creating the playlists just isn't worth my time & effort.

I have searched the internet, but there are no clear updated answers on how to accomplish this. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: The answer is that it is not possible.

Comment: "Uploading or importing your personal music to Amazon Music is no longer available."   https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=help_search_1-6?ie=UTF8&nodeId=GGXLPHTT5EWTUL4M&qid=1597301384&sr=1-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is at the moment not possible to import playlists.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your personal music files in any supported file type using Amazon Music for PC and Mac.

Supported File Types:

```
.mp3    Standard non-DRM file format (including Amazon Digital Music Store purchases)
.m4a    AAC files (Windows and Mac, including iTunes purchases) and Apple Lossless files* (Mac OS only)
.wma*   Windows Media Audio files (Windows only)
.wav*   Uncompressed music files
.ogg*   Ogg Vorbis audio files
.flac*  Free Lossless Audio Codec files
.aiff*  Audio Interchange Audio Format
```

*For these file types, only eligible files that match Amazon's catalog can be uploaded.

**Note:** Non-MP3 and Non-AAC files that are not matched and cannot be uploaded can be converted to either MP3 (.mp3) or AAC (.m4a) using your computer's default media player. Once converted, these files can be uploaded using Amazon Music for PC and Mac. Please see your default media player's Help section for instructions.

**[https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201379270)**